# Trying to extract co-ordinates from a Tweet [sub-string of a string in Excel]

Tags: excel, string, tweets

I have extracted Tweets from Twitter using Twitter IDs. The tool I am using extracts lots of features and appends them together in one cell in a .csv file. There are multiple files and each file varies in size but contains roughly one million rows. I am now in the painful process of splitting each string into columns, where each column represents a feature.

So far, I have been able to split the features because each feature name is unique (it only appears only once in the entire cell) using the below combination of Excel functions:

`=MID(A4,FIND("retweet_count",A4)+15,FIND("favorite_count",A4)-FIND("""retweet_count",A4)-18)`

In this example, I am able to select only the text between "retweet_count" and "fovourite_count", which is an integer value, showing the number of retweets the tweet received. The numbers ('+15' and '-18') simply cut out the feature names themselves. This approach is not working for the tweet co-ordinates.

Below is a link to a sample of my file (my one-drive), which contains 4 strings and the features I've managed to split so far:

https://1drv.ms/f/s!At39YLF-U90fhJwCdEuzAc2CGLC_fg

Only tweets 3 and 4 contain co-ordinates (the other 2 were not geo-tagged). Using the above approach is not working, as can be seen in cells M4 and M5, which say "null", when cells A4 and A5 contain co-ordinates.

I would be very appreciative if someone could suggest a dynamic way to extract co-ordinates from the string in column A, based on the structure of the string in column A. I say dynamic, as you cannot simply select a fixed position in the string, as it's length will differ for each tweet. So far, I have tried to use larger strings that incorporate multiple features, e.g. ""Point","coordinates" " rather than just "coordinates" but this had led to difficulties dealing with speech marks. I then tried using char(34), which I say in some other posts but I had no success with this approach.

Thanks in advance for any help,

Chris

Comment: The co-ordinates only ever relate to one location (i.e. the same value) but they appear in the string twice. I've tried to extract the coordinates from both of these places with the approach I mentioned in the question but could not get it to work.

I have never worked with VBA, so I would like to avoid it. If VBA is the only option, then I am happy to attempt it. It's worth mentioning that I will have approximately 150 files to repeat the process for, hence I have gone for the formulae approach, so I can simply paste into each file and double click to apply to all cells in each file.

Comment: I was about to post an answer with VBA (adapted from a project of mine) but I realized that in this case, a worksheet function should suffice.  See answer below.

Answer (score 2):

What you're doing is **not** the *proper* way to parse JSON, but can suffice nonetheless for small-to-medium term needs.

This formula will extra a set of coordinates from a tweet in cell `A4`:

```
=MID(A4,FIND("""coordinates"":[",A4)+15,FIND("]",A4,FIND("""coordinates"":[",A4)+15)-(FIND("""coordinates"":[",A4)+15))
```

...so placed in `M4` on your sample spreadsheet, it returns:

```
-26.8321,-71.1199
```

**However**, I have a suspicion as to your end-goal...  If your goal is realtime earthquake location data, unless there's a reason you need to use Twitter specifically, it is a *terrible* data source, for *many* reasons, and there are *many* better free places to get (or scrape) live earthquake data than this.

On the other hand, if this is a *learning project* and the data is inconsequential, then this is a good way to learn about text functions (but not much more!).

---

Maybe there's a reason you're scraping *tweets* specifically, but just in case there isn't, here's an example of one (of many) realtime (and **trustworthy**) data sources out there...

To retrieve XML containing all earthquakes activity this year, between Alaska and Coastal B.C., with magnitude >= 3.0:

- [Click this link](https://earthquake.usgs.gov/fdsnws/event/1/query?format=xml&starttime=2018-01-01&endtime=2018-02-04&minmagnitude=3&minlatitude=45&maxlatitude=62&minlongitude=-156&maxlongitude=-116)
- [USGS Earthquake Catalog API Documentation](https://earthquake.usgs.gov/fdsnws/event/1/)

Or, to get the same data as a downloaded CSV file (directly into Excel), just change "XML" to "CSV" in the URL, or [click this link](https://earthquake.usgs.gov/fdsnws/event/1/query?format=csv&starttime=2018-01-01&endtime=2018-02-04&minmagnitude=4&minlatitude=45&maxlatitude=62&minlongitude=-156&maxlongitude=-116).

[image: csv data]

The same source has data available in numerous formats.

One last thing to consider: Excel has various built-in methods of parsing data such as XML, JSON, CSV, etc.  You may be trying to re-write functionality that's already built in to Excel.

Comment: ashleedawg - thanks for your input. I have a Python script for scraping Twitter. The project I am working on is for a dissertation. I am looking to build a tool that can scrape Tweets and identify a disaster or crisis. I have a dataset provided by CrisisNLP, which I will be using to train and test what I build. The above process is to extract the features from the strings, so I can then identify some relationships. This is the starting point but if you have better suggestions, I would be very grateful for your input. Please note that the focus is on Twitter and the event type is broad.

Comment: Alright, if the data source must be Twitter (which would be far too limiting, complicated, inaccurate and prone to problems than "official" disaster alert sources) then I guess you have your work cut out for you!   Nonetheless, the formula at the beginning of my answer should extract the coordinate set without issue,

Comment: Another API you may be interested in: http://apidoc.rwlabs.org/#disasters

Comment: The above is very helpful - thanks. The approach I took to parse the data wasn't a "choice" per se, just the only way I know how (I am very new to coding). I will look into parsing in more detail, to better understand more structured ways of doing this. As for Twitter being a source, this is just my dissertation question that interests me and I think it could be powerful if implemented with some success. I will look into your suggestions and perhaps incorporate them for benchmarking purposes - thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Say we have a string and want to extract all the text between a **leading encapsulator** and a **trailing encapsulator**.  So in this string:

123alphagoldomega678

We want everything between *alpha* and *omega*; we want *gold*.
This approach is useful for a string in an Excel worksheet cell.  It assumes that the environment supports *VBA*.  Consider the following User Defined Function:

```
Public Function eXtractor(inpt As String, lead As String, trail As String) As String
    eXtractor = ""
    If InStr(1, inpt, lead) = 0 Then Exit Function
    ary = Split(inpt, lead)
    If lead = trail Then
        eXtractor = ary(1)
    Else
        bry = Split(ary(1), trail)
        eXtractor = bry(0)
    End If
End Function
```

[image]

If the leading and trailing encapsulators are the same, we still get the text between them.
If there are several set of encapsulators in the same string, the UDF() will return the first instance.

Comment: Many thanks for the above. After looking into parsing correctly, I am a little confused. The tool I use to extract the tweets and obtain the string I am trying to parse involves running a line of code in the terminal and executing a .jar file. I then get this string in a .txt file, which I convert to .csv for parsing. Now I know aware of parsing, I'd now like to do it in Python, as this will be helpful to obtain the hashtags (they are still appended in a column with my current approach), plus it will be useful for when I try and build a tool for doing this in real-time. Any suggestions? :)

Comment: @ChristopherLoynes Sadly, my answer only applies to parsing a string in an Excel worksheet cell.